# Get sum of the column in odoo8

Tags: function, sum, odoo-8

I want to calculate the sum of the column 'Montant crédit' on `account.bank.statement`. I tried to use _get_sum_entry_encoding but it those not work.

See the picture:

[image: sum of column]

Comment: May we see what you have tried so far? Is your attempt in the form of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of test and with the help of Kbir here is the solution :
.py :

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm, osv
class sale_order_line(orm.Model):
_inherit = 'account.bank.statement'
_name = 'account.bank.statement'

def _get_tot(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
res = {}
cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id ="+str(ids[0])+"")
data = cr.fetchone()
for re in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
 res[re.id] = data[0]
return res


def _get_statement_from_line(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    result = {}
    for line in self.pool.get('account.bank.statement.line').browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        result[line.statement_id.id] = True
    return result.keys()

_columns = {

'totm': fields.function(_get_tot, 'totm',type='float',
       store = {
            'account.bank.statement': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, context=None: ids, ['line_ids','move_line_ids'], 10),
            'account.bank.statement.line': (_get_statement_from_line, ['amount'], 10),
       }),
      }
```

.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
   <data>
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_order_form_ftz">
        <field name="name">view.order.form.ftz</field>
        <field name="model">account.bank.statement</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_formfz" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='balance_start']" position="after">
            <field name="totm" string="Montant total"/>
          </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
 </openerp>
```

I think you again Kabir.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
 def _get_tot(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id ="+str(ids)+"")
    data = cr.fetchall() 
    for re in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
         res[re.id] = data 

    return res
```

Comment: hi, i want to try with python code because i wanna to call the total  value in other function

Comment: yes i try it ..plz see the answer.. i get this error : i get this error : KeyError: 'statement_id'

Comment: hi, i try it soo if i do that : cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id='5'") i get the sum correctly but whene i use this : id = 5 
    cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id=id") i don't get a value ... i don t know why

Comment: thanks , it work , but i still need to get the account.bank.statement id value.. as replace '5' by the id value

Comment: try this _get_tot(self,cr,uid,ids,context):

Comment: i try this : def _get_tot(self, cr, uid, ids, context):
 id =name.id
 cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id ="+str(id)+"") but it doesn't work i get the error : _get_tot() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Comment: i add that and still give me : _get_tot() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)def _get_tot(self,cr,ids,values,context):
 current_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
 idstate = current_obj.id
 cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_bank_statement_line WHERE statement_id ="+str(idstate)+"")
 return cr.fetchall()

Comment: i get this error : _get_tot() takes at least 6 arguments (4 given)